# How to fix my HTML so it will work

Tags: html

Hi, I am writing html code for square box I need 4 cells and in the 4 cells I need to divide 4 more parts only thing it's breaking other parts for me:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>This page is Mohan</title>
</head>
        <center>
<table>
                <tr>
                    <td>

                        <div style="width:250px;height:250px;border:1px solid #0000FF;"><br>
                        <div align:"left"="" style="width:80px;height:80px;border:1px solid #0000FF;"></div><br><br>

                        <div align:"right" style="width:80px;height:80px;border:1px solid #0000FF;"></div><br>
                        <div align:"right" style="width:80px;height:80px;border:1px sloid #0000FF;"></div>

                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
        </center>
</table>
</html>
```

Please, could you get me through this I am still learner. This is only in html page and couldn't make it.
I have been trying for more than 3 hours.

Comment: You forgot a `<body>` tag. Can't have any "content" in an html document WITHOUT a `<body>...content here...</body>` tag to contain it all.

Comment: Also, [`<center>` is deprecated.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTML/Element/center), as is the `align` attribute. use CSS instead

Comment: hi David  i will do that whatever i make it went good the only thing is i need to make two more box two insert on that square box and i need to put one horizontal and one vertical line in the square box inside of those square boxes too.

Comment: Please read some html tutorials. Stackoverflow is more for specific questions or problems and not for teaching.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>This page is Mohan</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div style="width:250px;height:250px;border:1px solid #0000FF;">
                    <br>
                    <div align:"left"="" style="width:80px;height:80px;border:1px solid #0000FF;"></div>
                    <br><br>
                    <div align:"right" style="width:80px;height:80px;border:1px solid #0000FF;"></div>
                    <br>
                    <div align:"right" style="width:80px;height:80px;border:1px sloid #0000FF;"></div>
                </div>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Notice that I add a <body> tag for the content and took the <center> tag as David explained you clearly above.

Comment: thats right third div align right its not coming to right in the box?

Answer (score 0):

Since you're already using tables, just nest another table inside of it. Also, you forgot opening and closing `<body>` tags. I recommend using CSS for positioning, and styling.

```
<html>
<head>
<title>This page is Mohan</title>
</head>
<body>

<center>

  <table>

    <tr>
      <td>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </td>
      <td>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </td>      
    </tr>

    <tr>
      <td>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </td>
      <td>

        <table>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
          </tr>
        </table>

      </td>      
    </tr>

  </table>

</center>

</body>
</html>
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HP7f8/

Comment: Hi! Try putting text inside of each <td></td> and you will see that it does work. Example: http://jsfiddle.net/HP7f8/

Answer (score 0):

i think your problem is been occurred because you are not closing your tags properly.

You are opening the < center > tag and then the < table > tag BUT you are closing the < /center >  tag first and then the < /table >  tag.

Just swap these two closing tags. Put the closing table tag first and then the center tag (and also as Chris mentioned don't forget the body tag ).

Hope this helped.